# Localization Cookie not being created in Blazor server-side app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I set up localization in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

and:

```
var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "de-DE", "sv-SE" };
app.UseRequestLocalization(supportedCultures);
```

I also added the following in the `body` section of the `_Host.cshtml` file:

```
@{
    this.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(
        new RequestCulture(
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)),
            new CookieOptions {
                Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1),
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
            }
    );
 }
```

I created a culture controller:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class CultureController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Set(string culture, string redirectUri)
    {
        if (culture != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(
                    new RequestCulture(culture, culture)),
                        new CookieOptions {
                            Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1),
                            SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
                        }
            );
        }

        return LocalRedirect(redirectUri);
    }
}
```

And a razor component which has a method to set the culture by doing:

```
private void Navigate(CultureInfo info)
{
    var uri = new Uri(navigationManager.Uri).GetComponents(UriComponents.PathAndQuery, UriFormat.Unescaped);
    var cultureEscaped = Uri.EscapeDataString(info.Name);
    var uriEscaped = Uri.EscapeDataString(uri);

    navigationManager.NavigateTo(
        $"Culture/Set?culture={cultureEscaped}&redirectUri={uriEscaped}",
        forceLoad: true);
}
```

Whilst debugging, the controller action is called with the correct parameters as expected. However, the localization cookie is not being created (checked the Application tab in the Developer tools in Chrome).

The cookie options are:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

I am also using a custom ticket store for authentication cookies and it is setup as follows:

```
services.AddSingleton<ITicketStore, CookieMemoryTicketStore>();
services.AddOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .Configure<ITicketStore>((options, store) => {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.SessionStore = store;
        });
```

**EDIT**

A blank Blazor server-side app with localization can be found in this [Github repo](https://github.com/cryo75/CultureTest). Changing locale still doesn't work.

**UPDATE**

The problem lies with the `CookiePolicyOptions` above. Culture cookie creation works if the cookie options are changed as follows:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
});
```

Which obviously I don't want to do. I need to implement the cookie consent.

How can I implement the cookie policy options and use the culture cookie too?

Comment: Did you install `Microsoft.Extensions.Localization`?

Comment: Have you tried to use F12 develop tool to check if the cookie has created from the server-side? It seems it doesn't add it well.

Comment: Package is installed. Cookie is not being created. Two other cookies are being created: `.AspNetCore.Cookies` and `.AspNetCore.Consent`.

Comment: Could you please run your code but without the code in `_Host.cshtml`, I don't understand the meaning of it?

Comment: @Nb777 Tried that and still no locale cookie. Forced a specific locale by doing `app.UseRequestLocalization("de-DE");` and the pages are displayed in the correct locale. So this excludes a problem the resource files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

Add function for `RequestLocalizationOptions` in startup:

```
   private RequestLocalizationOptions GetLocalizationOptions()
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "de-DE", "sv-SE" };

            var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
                .SetDefaultCulture("de-DE")
                .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures )
                .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures );

            return localizationOptions;
        }
```

Add this function to you `config`:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseRequestLocalization(GetLocalizationOptions());
```

Continue with your code...

Comment: This is the same as what I*m doing currently.

Comment: I know, but it tested and works fine, I thought that you could miss something, I ca not add as comment, so try copy and past, if doesn't work, I will delete it :)

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono, Do you have an update?

Comment: I'm creating a blank project to see if the cookie creation works or not.

Comment: Blank blazor app with culture implementation can be found here: `https://github.com/cryo75/CultureTest`. Setting of the localization cookie still doesn't work.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono, can you try to use another browser ? and check again with the same code

Comment: I can set the cookie, but it is not persisted among sessions despite expiration is set at a future date. Dev tools do not display any expiration date, just “session”

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Nb777 I can also confirm that the example app doesn't work, tested with Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
});
```

Controller:

```
if (culture != null)
{
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(
            new RequestCulture(culture, culture)), new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1), SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax });
}

return LocalRedirect(redirectUri);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It could be that the context your app is being run in is blocking the cookie. For example, I have noticed that my Blazor app being run within a Microsoft Teams client blocks the setting of the .AspNetCore.Culture cookie. When I go to the Blazor app through the browser directly, I can see it being set correctly.

If this is the case for you, unfortunately, I have no solution for the cookie approach to work. As a workaround, what you could do is manually set the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture properties on the current thread wherever localization is relevant. Preferably, this should be somewhere on a top-level thread. You can set it like so:

```
 public static class ThreadExtensions
 {
    public static void SetCulture(this Thread thread, string culture)
    {
         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(culture)) return;
         var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
         Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
         Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
    }
 }
```

In Blazor, I've seen the need to add this at the top of your component HTML area like

```
@{
    Thread.CurrentThread.SetCulture(_culture);
    <div>@Localizer["Title"];</div>
}
```