# Blazor language cookie not persisting properly especially in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, localization, blazor-server-side

I tried a similar approach to what is described [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73551303/localization-cookie-not-being-created-in-blazor-server-side-app) for my blazor-server app.

I implemented a language chooser calling the controller setting the cookie. Display language changes correctly, the cookie is indeed located with the debugger console.

When I open a new **TAB** and navigate to the app, the language loads correctly, cookie is there, all fine.

However, when I open a new **WINDOW** or I **restart the application**, the cookie sometimes disappears but not always (cache is not cleared in browser settings btw). I observe this for all browsers I tested - especially on restart, I suppose this can be because of the debugging environment...

In Chrome specifically, however, I see that the cookie is removed from *Storage->Cookies*, but there is a language key-value pair in *Storage->Local Storage* containing my selected language when re-starting the app or opening the app in a new window (in both cases).

Is this a known Chrome behavior?

Is there a way to ensure the cookie persists as is? Or should I load the values from local storage to set the language cookie again manually before first load of a new session?

As a side note: I use an antiforgery cookie as well, which persists correctly in Chrome in my tests.